# Water (at different pressures) Flowing Through a Pipe

Tags: pressure, water, flow

[image]

> Which direction will water flow through this hose?

My response to this question was that the water would flow from the lower faucet/"pipe" to the higher one due to pressure differences. I reasoned that since the water-pressure was higher at the lower faucet, it would cause water to flow to the higher pipe where pressure was relatively lower. However, this does not appear to be the accepted answer:

> **Water won't flow through the hose**
>
> Even though the hose has water inside it, the weight of the water will counteract the difference in pressure so that all the water remains still.

If this is true (which I don't understand how it is), is there a rigorous (ie mathematical) proof for this through which I can see exactly why?

---

Taken from https://brilliant.org/courses/puzzle-science/flow-3/pressure-2-diagrammar/3/ (behind a paywall)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I reasoned that since the water-pressure was higher at the lower faucet...

*Why* is the pressure higher at the lower faucet?  It is because of the additional weight of the water pushing on the lower faucet that is not pushing on the upper one.  This difference is $\rho g h$.

The same reasoning happens on the "pipe" side of the connection as on the "tank" side of the connection.  You have the same fluid (same density), you have the same gravitational field, and you have the same vertical distance between the connecting points.   Therefore the fluid in the pipe will have the same pressure as the fluid in the tank.  With no pressure differences from one side to the other, the fluid will not flow.